# is this violating the SOLID principles?

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

i have something like this in my project, the project it's kinda finished already (it's working)
i just want know if it is ok with the SOLID principles

```
static public class Tools
{
    static public GetProduct(this id){...}

    static public GetProductCategory(this id){...}

    static public GetUser(this id){...}

    // I also have here methods like IsStringNull ...
    // IsNull IsFalse, lots of stuff, everything static
}
```

and the usage is like this

```
var UserThatCreatedCategoryForThisProduct = 
      prodId.GetProduct().CategoryId.GetProductCategory().Creator.GetUser();
```

i know that is obvious that it's violates the SRP, but this class is static and it contains static methods that are independent one from each other, and it's kind off the same if i would create a static class for each method

Comment: These are extension methods? The syntax looks a bit off.

Comment: @peterchen: The usage example shows that is definitely the plan, good catch (I read it and didnt even notice that - that's a really bad idea!)

Comment: +1 For a good question: And yes...this violates SRP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Far as I can see, there are a lot of SOLID violations right here!

- Violations of Single Responsibility Principle - First you have data access methods for several classes, second you have helper methods (IsStringNull, IsNull, etc) intertwined with them.
- Violations of Interface Segragation Principle (as mentioned by Ruben) - If I were only concerned for Products, why do I need exposure to methods that get Users?

I'm sure there are some others, but these are the glaring ones.

**UPDATE** Now that someone commented on it, I think they're right; the code above looks like it's some form of *extension method abuse*.

For example I don't believe Data Access should be relegated to extension methods, or worse, a class named "Tools".

It'd probably make more sense to have a base class (on a totally different namespace and/or assembly) that abstracts your data access generalities, then inherit one data access class for each unique domain object (e.g., UserDAO, ProductDAO, etc). Do understand that my assumption here is that by GetProduct or GetUser you actually mean GetFromDatabase.

The rest of the helper methods do belong to extensions so they're fine.

Comment: actually i have this DAO classes, and they are used inside of the methods of the Tools class

Comment: Well, again, SRP. Your Tool class is doing too much as is. If you have DAO classes you can group them together in a UserManager or ProductManager class where all the CRUD and other functionality are. Extension methods are supposed to add functionality without mucking existing classes, NOT hide existing functionality from their real locations.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your examples, there's definitely an ISP and a SRP and probably a Law of Demeter (not SOLID but...) violation going on at the very least.

IMNSHO You're far better off reading articles on SOLID (or buying [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C# by Robert C. Martin and Micah Martin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857258) which is excellent throughout and one of the most useful books I've read in recent years) than asking for piecemeal advice on the interwebs for this type of thing.

If you want a shortcut (you don't though - the books and PDFs have examples that explain things very well!), these Hanselminutes podcasts with Uncle Bob are very good:

- [Hanselminutes Podcast 145 - SOLID Principles with Uncle Bob - Robert C. Martin](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast145SOLIDPrinciplesWithUncleBobRobertCMartin.aspx)
- [Hanselminutes Podcast 171 - The Return of Uncle Bob](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast171TheReturnOfUncleBob.aspx)

edit: Nabbed the SRP from [Jon Limjap](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372/jon-limjap) and [ppiotrowicz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/71965/ppiotrowicz)

Comment: What's the alternative? Surely not making `UserThatCreatedCategoryForThisProduct` a property / extension method of ProductID?!

Comment: peterchen, this is actually a very deep topic that will take a lot of training and/or practice to get. The jump from functional/procedural mindset in software development to a truly object-oriented one is a vast gap to cover, unfortunately.

Comment: @Jon - fair enough. Still, to me the access pattern seems to be imposed by the data structure, which *usually* is more *solid* (pardon the pun) than the processing code.

Answer (score 0):

It's violating SOLID principles in many ways.

- it's not following single responsibility principle, because i't doing at least 3 different things (returning products, returning customers, string operations?)
- it's violating open closed principle by not being open for extension